# postgres search columns case insensitive

Tags: node.js, postgresql

As title really... im running

```
db.any('SELECT * from films WHERE title = $1', query.term).then(function(data) {
        res.status(200).json({status: 'success', data: data});
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return next(err);
    });
```

It works, but if you search for '**c**ar' it wont find '**C**ar' in the DB, you have to search '**C**ar'... I could force lower case, then transform it back on the frontend, but that seems broken, even more so if the title was 'A Car Film'.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem is with the SQL, and not with `pg-promise` library. You should change your question entirely for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for equality, `Car` <> `car`, thus if you want to do it, you should use different operator:

```
SELECT * from films WHERE title ilike $1
```

which will return true:

```
t=# select 'car' ilike 'Car';
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

also you can try [more aggressive approach](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html):

```
t=# create extension citext;
CREATE EXTENSION
t=# select citext 'car' = 'Car';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Perfect. Sorry for the dumb question. This is day 1 of me trying to learn this stuff

Comment: its not dumb - postgres is extremely reach for operators and thus extremely flexible. even up to level that `car` = `Car` can be true, but you have to explicitely tell why postgres should think that :)